# Getting user_defined attributes for a product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php-5.4

Is it possible to get all user-defined attributes for a product? Input: product_id, Output: a list of all user_defined attributes, excluding the system_attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$productId = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('çatalog/product')->load($productId);

$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsUserDefined()) {
        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    }
}
```